# VBA Word: How to let VBA ignore 1000 separator while calculating formfields?

Tags: vba, form-fields

I need your help with this. I have a small code which sums up the value of 10 formfields. The format of this formfields is set with the 1000 separator. The problem that I'm running into is that VBA now returns a value like 1.000 as 1. In other words: 1+10+100+1.000=112. How can I adjust the code so that it ignores the 1000 separator while calculating those formfields? Any help is much appreciated!

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("voattot").Result = Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat1").Result) _
+ Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat2").Result) + Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat3").Result) _
+ Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat4").Result) + Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat5").Result) _
+ Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat6").Result) + Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat7").Result) _
+ Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat8").Result) + Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat9").Result) _
+ Val(ActiveDocument.FormFields("betvoat10").Result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd Create a Seperate Function to parse the result string from the form field

```
Function GetFieldValue(FieldName as string)
Dim FF As FormField 
Dim Result As String
Dim Value As Double


Set FF = ActiveDocument.Formfields(FieldName)'Find the Form Field
Result = FF.Result                           'Get the Text from the Form Field
Result = Replace(Result, ",", "")            'Remove any commas
If Trim(Result) ="" Then
    GetFieldValue= 0                         'Return the numeric valu
ElseIf Isnumeric(Result) Then
    Value = CDbl(Result)                         'Convert to numeric value
    GetFieldValue= Value                          'Return the numeric value
Else
    Debug.Print "Not IsNumeric(""" & Result & """)"
    GetFieldValue= 0
End If
End Function
```

And then you can write your statement as

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("voattot").Result = GetFieldValue("betvoat1") _
+ GetFieldValue("betvoat2") + GetFieldValue("betvoat3") _
+ GetFieldValue("betvoat4") + GetFieldValue("betvoat5") _
+ GetFieldValue("betvoat6") + GetFieldValue("betvoat7") _
+ GetFieldValue("betvoat8") + GetFieldValue("betvoat9") _
+ GetFieldValue("betvoat10")
```

This also means you can put error trapping into your Function to deal with empty or non numeric values or missing form fields.
Whether it's worth bothering with that is up to you

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks all very logical, but I'm pretty new to VBA and I've never worked with Functions before and I can't get it to work. I've tried several things, but the most logical to me seems to put the Function apart from the sub with this calculation. When I run the script, it keeps giving me the error: "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined." What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just to be clear: I have to run the calculation in the Sub, as I want the code to run after some other codes which are in the same Sub.

Comment: put the function definition outside the Sub definition. The function will be evaluated as part of the Sub.

Comment: That doesn't work. It gives the same error message as I've mentioned above :(

Comment: Doh!   I'd called it "GetFieldVal" in the definition and "GetFieldValue" in  the sub body. No wonder it couldn't find a function defined under that name. I'll edit my answer to correct that

Comment: Thanks! It takes me further now, but it gives me a "run-time error 13: Type Mismatch" in the line "Value=CDbl(Result)" of the function. I've tried to find a solution myself, but I'm afraid my knowledge isn't advanced enough :( Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: My best guess is that you have empty fields whose result is the empty string "" and so when you try to evaluate CDbl("") you get that error. I've added an If Statement to catch that special case. It will also write to the Debug Stream if there are any other nonnumeric values that can't be converted. You can read the debug output in the immediate window (Ctrl+G to Show)

Comment: Yes, it works! You are my hero of the day. Thanks for putting so much time in it. Didn't mean anybody to write the code for me, but you literally did and I really appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's sometimes easier to show than to explain how to write things